# To get text from two textboxs and add the elements to an array

Tags: c#

I want to add the elements from the textboxes to the array but every time I try adding the names it throws an exception. I want to add the elements after the button is clicked.

```
   private void Grade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            double grade;


            nametextbox.Text = "";
            gradetextbox.Text = "";

           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
            grade = Convert.ToDouble(gradetextbox.Text);
            grades[i] += grade;



            name = nametextbox.Text;
            names[i] += name;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it says index out of range for names, and grade says format unhandled

Comment: Additionally, Where you define `grades[]` and are you sure about input from `gradetextbox` is convertible to a double?

Comment: No assuming user will input a number but for my tests I put a number in the grades box each time

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
gradetextbox.Text = "";
```

Which sets the `Text` property to an empty string. Then you do this:

```
grade = Convert.ToDouble(gradetextbox.Text);
```

which is trying to convert the empty string to a `double`, which clearly does not work so it throws an exception.

What you probably need is this:

```
private double[] grades = new double[10]; // 10 grades
private string[] names = new string[10]; // 10 names
private int currentIndex = 0;
private void Grade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentIndex > 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No more enteries allowed");
    }

    string name;
    double grade;

    if (double.TryParse(gradetextbox.Text, out grade))
    {
        grades[currentIndex] += grade;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Grade enterd is not a valid grade");
        return;// do nothing else
    }

    name = nametextbox.Text;
    names[i] += name;

    // now clear the textboxes so user can enter another value
    nametextbox.Text = "";
    gradetextbox.Text = "";
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
}
```

Comment: what about the index out of range error I have names hard coded into the array and  empty space for user input

Comment: Thank first part worked made a funny error and put those out of place